# Submit Rails 4 form with link instead of button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I see some issues similar but they seem contrived and mostly for previous versions of Rails.

What is the simplest way to submit a form with an anchor tag (link) instead of the normal button

```
<%= f.submit 'Search', :class => "button expand"%>
```

What is the most concise way (best practice) way to change that to a link that submits?

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to do that? Anyway, simply add a handler to the click event of the link, which submits the form.

Comment: Just style your button to look like a link or use some Javascript to submit the form. This isn't specific to Rails.

Comment: I have seen it referenced as a question in a few places, so I was just curious if there is a Rails-way or helper that makes it simpler to do, but based on the answers its just javascript that makes the desired outcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I often use js/jquery to submit forms. It's very useful if the submit button is outside of the form or if there is more than one button that submits the same form.

```
$(".submit-btn").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#form-id").submit();
});
```

The `event.preventDefault();` prevents the default button/submit behaviour.

Here is a coffeescript example I have used in a rails 4 project:

```
ready = ->
  if $("#form-id").length > 0
    $(".submit-btn").click (event) ->
      event.preventDefault()
      $("#form-id").submit()

$(document).ready ready
$(document).on "page:load", ready
```

Also note, this way the link can be any type of element - not necessarily a submit button. You do not have to have the submit button inside the form, but if you do the `preventDefault` will prevent the default form submission behaviour.

Comment: This does not seem to work on Rails 5, perhaps due to issues with the form authenticity token.

Answer (score 5):

**Submit**

To extend the answers provided already, HTML forms have to be submitted with a `submit` button.

I'm not sure exactly what special characteristics the `submit` button has over a link - it essentially calls the `submit` action, which a link cannot ([info](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)):

[image]

--

**Link**

This means if you wish to replace a submit button with a link, you'll essentially have to mimick the `submit` method in your application. This can be done with JS (JQuery):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "#your_link", function(){
   $("#form").submit();
});

#app/views/controller/your_view.html.erb
<%= form_tag your_path, id: "form" do %>
    <%= link_to "Submit", your_path, id: "your_link" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is so simple:

Then:

```
<%= f.submit '', :class => "hidden", :id => 'form_submit_button' %>
content_tag(:a, 'Submit', :name => 'submit', :id => 'submit_link')
```

and in JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click","#submit_link",function() {
        $('#form_submit_button').click();
    });
});
```

I am not sure about exact sytax so there might be some syntax error. Feel free to ask for more help.

Comment: You don't need to add the submit button and hide it. Just don't include it at all.

Comment: But I think jquery has deprecated the form.submit() action. otherwise it is good not to include the hidden button

Comment: Deprecated? Where did you get that info?

Comment: As I told "I think" not sure heard about it by someone.

Comment: Oh okays I went through the documentation and it says nothing about that. Didn't mean offence.