# Make span element submit an edit form

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a pretty, bootstrappy form that looks like (in rails & HTML)

```
<%= form_for(current_user) do |f| %>
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <%= f.text_field :location, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Where are you?", 'aria-describedby' => 'basic-addon2' %>
    <span type="submit" name="commit" class="input-group-addon btn btn-success" id="basic-addon2" style="color: white;">Go!</span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But using the above, nothing actually happens when I hit the "Go!" button.

I can get my form to succesfully submit if I use the code:

```
<%= form_for(current_user) do |f| %>
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <%= f.text_field :location, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Where are you?", 'aria-describedby' => 'basic-addon2' %>
    <%= f.submit "Go!", class: "input-group-addon btn btn-success", id: "basic-addon2", style: "color: white;"  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My problem is that I'm having trouble merging both versions, i.e. to retain the aesthetics of the former while adding the functionality of the latter. Every way that I have tried to arrange spans within buttons or buttons within spans or other weird combos, nothing manages to do what I want. I can make the attributes of the `<span>` and the `<button>` (produced by f.submit) exactly the same, the only difference in the HTML my browser sees is that one is a `<span>` and the other is a `<button>`.

Can anyone think of a way for me to merge these two concepts?

Comment: `span` doesn’t have a `type` or a `name` attribute. You can not just interchange HTML elements willy-nilly, and expect them to have the same functionality … And if it is a certain _visual look_ that you are after, then you should use the appropriate element, and _format_ it via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

you see you can not use a link in span or something,  cause this submit button works as the post method via the browser. while the links goes in get method.  but there is a solution for any element to work as submit button,  just follow this instruction..  [Submit Rails 4 form with link instead of button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771281/submit-rails-4-form-with-link-instead-of-button)

Comment: If it's a dupe then mark as a dupe with the link to the dupe.

Comment: No no its okay ... I am sorry .

Comment: No worries; just confusing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always trigger the `submit` event when you click the `span` tag:

```
# Inside your document.ready function in your .js file

$('#my_span').on('click', function() {
  $('#my_form').submit();
});
```

A hacky way, but it works.

Comment: It's not hacky, that's how you do it.